# Mathematica notebook into latex document

Tags: conversion, wolfram-mathematica

Whereas

- Mathematica allows us to dump an entire notebook into a readable LaTeX file.  However, the formatting of that file is not optimal.
- There are many posts on how to "beautify" a single Mathematica equation into LaTeX.  But, this procedure can not be manually implemented for a notebook containing over 100 in/out.

So my question is whether there is a LaTeX style sheet which can take the `.tex` file dumped by Mathematica and display it in a more appealing way.

Following is a sample of the generated code:

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Define the load (omitting the d$\theta $) { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } }

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{dP}'=w R;}\)
\end{doublespace}

\section*{Primary Structure; Externally Applied load { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } }

\subsection*{\textup{ Determine horizontal reaction at B by taking moment with respect to Z (CCW +ve)}}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{x1}=R \text{Cos}[\alpha ]; \text{x2}=R \text{Cos}[\theta ]; \text{y0}=R(1-\text{Sin}[\alpha ]);}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{SigMZ}= -\text{BX} \text{y0}+\int _{\alpha }^{\pi /2}(\text{x1}-\text{x2}) \text{dP}' d\theta }\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\frac{1}{2} R^2 w ((\pi -2 \alpha ) \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ]))-\text{BX} R (1-\text{Sin}[\alpha ])\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{Sol1}=\text{Solve}[\text{SigMZ}\text{==}0, \text{BX}]; \text{BX}= \text{BX}\text{/.}\text{Sol1}[[1]]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(-\frac{R w (-2+\pi  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]-2 \alpha  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 \text{Sin}[\alpha ])}{2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ])}\)
\end{doublespace}

\subsection*{\textup{ Determine vertical reaction by taking summation of forces in the y direction}}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{BY}=\int _{\alpha }^{\pi /2} \text{dP}'d\theta }\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(R w \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\alpha \right)\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{CX}=\text{BX}}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(-\frac{R w (-2+\pi  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]-2 \alpha  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 \text{Sin}[\alpha ])}{2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ])}\)
\end{doublespace}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting question; +1 `:)` Can you give us a short example of the kind of document Mathematica outputs?  Depending on how Mathematica handles it, this could be easy.  Otherwise, there's always the preprocessing option.

Comment: For mathematica docs(not latex), I... let here 2 links in spanish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTBIY8rr9WI   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voU9tJIG6MI

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to include a sample of the mathematica output. I presume that you are also a latex and Mathematica user, and as such can save an entire notebook as latex (it is one of the save options).

Comment: I use Mathematica, but I don't have a ready copy on-hand. You can simply export to LaTeX, open the file in a text editor, and copy/paste everything into your original post.  (If you aren't aware, you can `edit` your post via the button to the *far* left of your signature.)

Comment: @MikaIke I'm sorry, but I don't really see the relevance of those videos `:(` What do they discuss?

Comment: to obtain documents from amthematica, but not related to latex

Comment: Well this is the "ugly" latex code generated by mathematica:

Comment: @victor Who has implemented the conversion tools doesn't know even the basics of TeX nor of math notation, where the cosine of an angle is written `\cos\alpha` and surely ***not*** `\text{Cos}[\alpha]`. `:-(`

Comment: Again, goes to prove that they really do not want to see a notebook sent to LaTeX, hence the lousy job.

Comment: An (untested) possibility is to using IPython instead of Mathematica. There is an IPython extension https://github.com/bjedwards/IPython-mathematicamagic-extension that is supposed to interop with Mathematica. IPython generates fairly clean LaTeX code.

Comment: "However, the formatting of that file is not optimal." You're being too nice. I've seen the output before, and it is simply **horrible**.

Comment: @egreg `\text{Cos}[\alpha]` is in fact reasonable. They're trying to replicate what's displayed in a Mathematica notebook, where cosine in the default output style (called `StandardForm` in Mathematica jargon) is `Cos[α]`. If you ask Mathematica to display in `TraditionalForm`, then the LaTeX output for `Cos[x]//TraditionalForm` will be `\noindent\(\cos (x)\)`, which is more TeXish.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the equation positioning, I've added the `fleqn` option to the document class, but apart from that, the following is the only additions to the preamble to format the document contents:

```
% New stuff
\usepackage{environ}
\renewcommand{\pmb}[1]{#1}% Remove bold math
\RenewEnviron{doublespace}{%
  \let\noindent\relax%
  \let\(\relax\let\)\relax%
  \[\BODY\]
}

\let\oldtext\text
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Sin}=0
    \cos
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Cos}=0
    \sin
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Tan}=0
    \tan
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{==}=0
    \equiv
  \else
    \oldtext{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
```

The intent is to

- remove the use of `\pmb` in math context, since I don't know what it would be used for;
- remove the `doublespace` environment's use as a display math equation. Instead, remove the use of `\noindent`, `\(` and `\)` and rather set the contents inside `\[`...`\]`;
- update `\text` to condition on its argument, thereby replacing `\text{Cos}` by `\cos`, as well as other possible constructions.

This is for sure not perfect, and could be improved. I also assumed that the superfluous spacing inside sectional titles is due to the author adding them, and should be removed manually.

Here's a complete translation of the document:

[image]

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

% New stuff
\usepackage{environ}
\renewcommand{\pmb}[1]{#1}% Remove bold math
\RenewEnviron{doublespace}{%
  \let\noindent\relax%
  \let\(\relax\let\)\relax%
  \[\BODY\]
}

\let\oldtext\text
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Sin}=0
    \cos
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Cos}=0
    \sin
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Tan}=0
    \tan
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{==}=0
    \equiv
  \else
    \oldtext{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Define the load (omitting the d$\theta $)}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{dP}'=w R;}\)
\end{doublespace}

\section*{Primary Structure; Externally Applied load}

\subsection*{\textup{Determine horizontal reaction at B by taking moment with respect to Z (CCW +ve)}}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{x1}=R \text{Cos}[\alpha ]; \text{x2}=R \text{Cos}[\theta ]; \text{y0}=R(1-\text{Sin}[\alpha ]);}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{SigMZ}= -\text{BX} \text{y0}+\int _{\alpha }^{\pi /2}(\text{x1}-\text{x2}) \text{dP}' d\theta }\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\frac{1}{2} R^2 w ((\pi -2 \alpha ) \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ]))-\text{BX} R (1-\text{Sin}[\alpha ])\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{Sol1}=\text{Solve}[\text{SigMZ}\text{==}0, \text{BX}]; \text{BX}= \text{BX}\text{/.}\text{Sol1}[[1]]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(-\frac{R w (-2+\pi  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]-2 \alpha  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 \text{Sin}[\alpha ])}{2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ])}\)
\end{doublespace}

\subsection*{\textup{Determine vertical reaction by taking summation of forces in the y direction}}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{BY}=\int _{\alpha }^{\pi /2} \text{dP}'d\theta }\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(R w \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\alpha \right)\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{CX}=\text{BX}}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(-\frac{R w (-2+\pi  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]-2 \alpha  \text{Cos}[\alpha ]+2 \text{Sin}[\alpha ])}{2 (-1+\text{Sin}[\alpha ])}\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, much much better. However how to remove all that blank space in between the equations (i.e. make them single space for instance).

Comment: @victor: You could probably add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to your preamble and change the `doublespace` environment to use ``$\displaystyle\BODY$ \\`` instead of `\[\BODY\]`.

Comment: At the risk of sounding too "greedy", lsat but not least how to discernate the input from the output (with the number if possible). Once you have all those questions resolved, might as well put together a nice package to transfer mathematica code into latex (very badly needed).

Answer (score 2):

You could export your whole Mathematica notebook to pdf and then with pdfpage pack use it in the latex doc

preamble:

```
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
.
.
.
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1]{notebook.pdf}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already do that, but it occupies too much space.

Comment: This was my solution when I faced this problem.  Yes, it makes for larger file size which is the downside.